# How to use Pi register Plugin in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress 3.7, and I have installed pi register plugin, but I can't find any shortcode so that I may include it in my custom template, can any one help me in regard so I may use it properly.

Comment: go to plugin manager and click "edit plugin". there you can find a readme.txt file, i think it will describe how to use this plugin in your custom theme.

Comment: is there any short code? @ALi

Answer (score -1):

There is no short-code for pie chart..

If you check checkbox anyone can register at Settings --> General, Then you can see register page. http://yourwesite.com/wp-login.php?action=register There you can check your settings of register page.

It means your changes will be loaded automatically with out using any short-code..